# How to persist and query userconnections via Hibernate in Spring Social?

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, spring-social

How can I persist and query `userconnection`s via Hibernate in Spring Social?
The situation:
We have to introduce Spring Social in a legacy web application. This legacy system uses Hibernate. The problem is, that in Spring Social the `userconnection`s are persisted via `SpringTemplate` (classes `JdbcUsersConnectionRepository` and `JdbcConnectionRepository`).

From my limited understanding, I have two options:

1. Use it as it is.
2. Implement a custom `ConnectionRepository` and `UsersConnectionRepository`, which use the existing Hibernate infrastructure

Option 1 is not what I want, as I then have to invest a lot of effort to configure properly a second persistence framework (multi-threading, connection-pooling, etc.).
Option 2 quickly solves my problems, but in the long run may lead to hidden or unhidden problems when upgrading to new Spring Social versions.

As both options are not really satisfying my question:
What would you propose? Do you know better options?